# Amazon MWS API - How do I get product reviews from Amazon?

Tags: amazon-mws, review

I am using Amazon MWS API to list our products and other things as inventory/orders management on Amazon but I am not able to get the customer reviews on our products from Amazon. Is there anyone who can let me guide how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customer Reviews can be retrieved through the Amazon Product Advertising API, they are not available in MWS.

The [ItemLookup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) and [ItemSearch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html) calls both have a parameter `ResponseGroup` which you can set to `Reviews`. The response will contain an `IFrameURL` that links to a HTML representation of all reviews of a product. Unfortunately there seems to be no way to actually pull the raw data - you'll have to parse the HTML if that is what you want to do.

This is an example of such a response (as shown [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_MotivatingCustomerstoBuy.html#GettingCustomerReviews))

```
<ItemLookupResponse>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <ASIN>0316067938</ASIN>
            <CustomerReviews>
                <IFrameURL>
                http://www.amazon.com/reviews/iframe?akid=[AWS Access Key ID]&asin=0316067938&exp=2011-08-01T17%3A54%3A07Z&linkCode=xm2&summary=0&tag=ws&truncate=256&v=2&sig=[Signature]
                </IFrameURL>
            </CustomerReviews>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

Comment: Here I have another set of questions....

Comment: Where can I get the linkcode from?

Comment: Where can I get the Tag, summary and Signature from?

Comment: The `Signature` for the Product Advertising API is described in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RequestAuthenticationArticle.html . I'm not sure, which summary, tags and linkcode you are referring to.

Comment: Hello, is there any option to get rating and reviews?